# Allow a required module access to the local scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm writing a script that fetches arbitrary JavaScript files that all want access to a window object. Therefore I want to spoof the window object for them to get the results I need.

```
// arbitrary.js
var foo = window.bar;
-> Error: window undefined.
```

I therefore want to inject a window object into the modules local scope. Pretend I don't have edit access for arbitrary.js

```
// server.js
global.window = {...};
require('./arbitrary");
```

This does not work because arbitrary.js specifically tries to access "window" and not "global.window" so it doesn't matter if I put objects on the global object. It seems I cannot inject objects into arbitrary.js' scope.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Maybe I should be using a different function from "require" to get the arbitrary.js code to run in the scope from which it was included? I haven't found any way to do this though. Should I use eval() in some way?

Comment: @jfriend00 Truly? I really hope I can avoid that.

Comment: I must be missing something, but what you describe should "just work." Just to confirm, you are running this in node and not browserifying it/putting it in the browser, right?

Comment: @go-oleg I am running this on Node (6.1.0). Basically I can do window = global.window and then it works. It seems like it doesn't consider global as the "bottom" scope but it has access to the global object itself. It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided actually works, at least on Node.js 6.2.0.

`arbitrary.js`:

```
var foo = window.bar
```

`server.js`:

```
global.window = {foo: "foo"}
require("./arbitrary.js")
```

Running `node server.js` doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Wait what? For me global.window.bar works but not window.bar. Is this intended behaviour? I'm running Node 6.1.0.

Can you assign things to window inside of arbitrary.js without issues too?

Comment: well that's odd. I guess I have some searching and debugging to do with my Node and its global object / scope. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the factory pattern.

```
global.window = {hi: "hello world"};
var arb = require('./arbitrary')(global.window);
arb.myFunc();
```

in your arbitrary.js:

```
module.exports = function(window){
    var foo = window.bar;

    function myFunc () { console.log(window.hi);}

    return {
       myFunc: myFunc
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember "Pretend I don't have edit access for arbitrary.js". I cannot put an exports in there.

Comment: Ah i missed that. I assumed you could access arbitrary because it seems silly to be loading js files that access a global object. Could i ask for the motivation behind this? Why would you purposely pollute your global scope?

Comment: I understand it seems silly. It's basically automatically built js-files that I cannot control how they are made. I don't want to edit them every time they are built (which is often) so I'd rather be able to make them run automatically however they are made.